# Restrict Android user location within city perimeters

Tags: android, geolocation, android-maps-v2, geofencing

I'm building an app where I need to apply bounds on user's location (Lat,Lng) to be within city perimeters like Uber. How can I achieve this?

This one is when within city perimeters

[image]

This one is not in city or Uber's service zone.

[image]

I have tried this approach. I'm using geocoder and fetching the address of the location and matching city parameters.

```
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1); 
        if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
        }
```

Can I use Geofencing? If yes then how?

Comment: Restrict the zoom level of your map with current location. say zoom level 17 to zoom level 12.

Comment: Nah, that is not a fix. User can search some arbitrary address.

Comment: Then you can use Geo fencing api; setting the radius to 10m-5km.

Comment: Geo fencing requires a background location service right?